# Trying to understand JS promises to eliminate a race condition

Tags: javascript, promise, race-condition

I'm working on a project in plain JS, and I've got a race condition that I'm trying to eliminate. I just encountered the concept of promises and I'm struggling with how they work.

Here's what I'm trying to do: the user can drag files to a drop zone, and a representation of that file gets created in a gallery, and it's supposed to go through a process that is represented by a progress bar:

```
var tracker = {}; // this will have dropped-file objects added
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

function newFile(id) {
     (declaration of various properties)
     var container = document.createElement('DIV');

     (then the creation of various elements within the container)

     var progress = new progbar(id);  // goes to a constructor to create the progress bar
     container.appendChild(progress);
     gallery.appendChild(container);

     this.id = id;
     this.container = container;
     this.progress = progress;

     this.removeMe = function() {
          this.progress.endprog();
          delete tracker[this.id];
     }

     return this;
}
```

Then elsewhere in the program, when the user drops a file into the drop area, we add a `tracker[id] = new newFile(id);`.

The problem comes if the user clicks the progress bar's "cancel" link: the file object's `removeMe()` method is invoked, it calls the end of the progress bar with `this.progress.endprog()`, and then deletes itself from the the tracker object.

If the user drops the same file, then I check `tracker` and if the file exists the process ends with an alert to the user. But if they've started the processing of that file and cancelled it, I want them to be able to drop the file again. So though I do leave behind the div of the cancelled file (so marked), the file's object is gone from `tracker` and so it can be dropped again.

What I'm concerned about is this:

```
this.progress.endprog();
delete tracker[this.id];
```

Both of those things need to happen, but if `progress.endprog{}` has not finished before the file (and thus the progress object itself) is deleted, then I'm worried about screwing things up.

I originally had a `set Timeout` on the deletion, but that still felt like a race condition, and I was looking for something more elegant and eliminate the race condition. But I'm floundering. Can a promise help? Is there some other way I'm missing?

EDIT: ADDING MORE DETAIL

A piece of information is important here that I forgot to include: the progress bar object makes various self-references:

```
function progbar(id) {
     (declaration of various properties)
     var bar = document.createElement('DIV');
     [file container].appendChild(bar);
     this.bar = bar;
     this.width = 0;
     this.fillup;

     this.startprog = function () {
          this.fillup = setInterval( [process to check for correct length] );
     }

     this.endprog = function () {
          [other stuff, and then...]
          clearInterval(this.fillup);
          [then more stuff]
     }

     return this;
 }
```

So you can see that there is at least a reference to the `setInterval` which is stored as a property of the object. If the file object is deleted before `endprog()` gets to this reference, will it not be trying to access a property that no longer exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 this.id = id;
 this.container = container;
 this.progress = progress;

 this.removeMe = function(id) {
      this.progress.endprog();
      delete tracker[id];
 }
```

Answering to your comment, maybe an option can be to move the `delete tracker[this.id];` inside the endprog function, so you can ensure is called at the end of this function, other more complex option can be the use of a process that only delete trackers with a given flag.

Comment: I should have added more detail, darn it. The endprog() function makes various references to its own properties. My concern is if tracker[id] is eliminated before endprog() finishes, then in the middle of endprog() the file object (and thus the progress bar object?) is deleted. So in the middle of endprog() its parent object may cease to exist. Does that make sense? I will edit the original to reflect this.

Comment: @user3281644 check the new answer

Comment: That is an idea. I think once the function is CALLED, it's called in its entirety. But if it's a method within an object I don't know. I think the solution is going to end up being a fileTracker object and a progressTracker object, so they can operate independently of each other but have similar IDs. That' feels less elegant and reliant upon coordinating IDs. I'll try your suggestion, to put the deletion at the end of the very last function call, see if that works. Thanks!

Comment: Andreu: It did work, to put the delete command inside endprog(). However I'm considering whether it's wise to have an object such as that delete itself when it has other methods besides its self-deletion. But it DID work!